# How to get LaTeX to work in IPython notebook?

Tags: ubuntu, latex, ipython, jupyter-notebook

I'm experimenting with IPython notebook. I can't get LaTeX to work:

```
$$ x + 3 $$
  File "<ipython-input-1-0f8a1bc96d90>", line 1
    $$ x + 3 $$
    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I'm using Ubuntu 12.04 and ipython 0.12.1. If upgrading to 0.13 would solve my problem, please explain how to do that, as my attempts have failed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to write latex you should write in in a Markdown cell, not in a code cell.

Still, consider migrating to 0.13, 0.12 cannot read notebook generated from newer version and has a design flaw in notebook format.

Comment: Thanks, wasn't aware of the difference. As for upgrading, consider it? I've been attempting it. Tell me how!

Comment: 12.04 is precise? if so, look at this PPA : https://launchpad.net/~jtaylor/+archive/ipython-dev.

Comment: Thanks, that's what I tried. I'll ask a new question later, detailing my failed upgrade.